# Special meaning of <> and anonymous arrays inside regex in Perl 6

Tags: arrays, regex, interpolation, raku

Outside regex, <> behaves more or less like single quotes. My shallow understanding seems to tell me that, inside regex, <> allows evaluation and interpolation of codes:

```
# Outside regex, <> acts like single quotes:
> my $x = <{"one"}>
{"one"}
> $x.WHAT
(Str)

# Inside regex, <> evaluates and interpolates:
> my $b="one";
one
> say "zonez" ~~ m/ <{$b}> /  # Evaluates {$b} then quotes: m/ one /
｢one｣
> say "zonez" ~~ m/ <$b> /    # Interpolates and quotes without {}
｢one｣
```

Because an array variable is allowed inside a regex, I suspect that the Perl 6 regex engine expends the array into OR's when there is <> inside regex surrounding the array.

I also suspect that in a user-defined character class, <[ ]>, the array [] inside <> more or less works like an anonymous array in a way similar to @a below, and the contents of the array (chars in the character class) are expended to OR's.

```
my @a = $b, "two";
[one two]
> so "zonez" ~~ m/ @a /;
True
> say "ztwoz" ~~ m/ <{[$b, "two"]}> / # {} to eval array, then <> quotes
｢two｣
> say "ztwoz" ~~ m/ <{@a}> /
｢two｣
> say "ztwoz" ~~ m/ <@a> /
｢two｣
> say "ztwoz" ~~ m/ one || two /  # expands @a into ORs: [||] @a;
# [||] is a reduction operator;
｢two｣
```

And char class expansion:

```
> say "ztwoz" ~~ m/ <[onetw]> / # like [||] [<o n e t w>];
｢t｣
> say "ztwoz" ~~ m/ o|n|e|t|w /
｢t｣
> my @m = < o n e t w >
[o n e t w]
> say "ztwoz" ~~ m/ @m /
｢t｣
```

I have not looked into the Rakudo source code, and my understanding is limited. I have not been able to construct anonymous arrays inside regex to prove that <> indeed constructs arrays inside regex.

So, is <> inside regex something special? Or should I study the Rakudo source code (which I really try not to do at this time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside of a regex `<>` acts like `qw<>`, that is it quotes and splits on spaces.

```
say <a b    c>.perl;
# ("a", "b", "c")
```

It can be expanded to

```
q :w 'a b    c'

Q :q :w 'a b    c'

Q :single :words 'a b    c'
```

I recommend reading [Language: Quoting Constructs](https://docs.perl6.org/language/quoting) as this is a more broad topic than can be discussed here.

This has almost nothing to do with what `<>` does inside of a regex.

The use of `<>` in regexes is not useful in base Perl 6 code, and `qw` is not that useful in regexes. So these characters are doing double duty, mainly because there are very few non-letter and non-number characters in ASCII. The only time it acts like `qw` is if the character immediately following `<` is a whitespace character.

---

Inside of a regex it can be thought of as injecting some code into the regex; sort of like a macro, or a function call.

```
/<{ split ';', 'a;b;c' }>/;
/ [ "a" | "b" | "c" ] /;
```

( Note that `|` tries all alternations at the same time while `||` tries the leftmost one first, followed by the next one, etc. That is `||` basically works the way `|` does in Perl 5 and PCRE. )

```
/<:Ll - [abc]>/
/ [d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z] / # plus other lowercase letters
```

```
/ <@a> /
/ [ "one" | "two" ] /
```

Note that `/ @a /` also dissolves into the same construct.

```
/ <?{ 1 > 0 }> /

# null regex always succeeds
/ [ '' ] /
```

```
/ <?{ 1 == 0 }> /

# try to match a character after the end of the string
# (can never succeed)
/ [ $ : . ] /
```

Those last two aren't quite accurate, but may be a useful way to think about it.

---

It is also used to call regex "methods".

```
grammar Foo {
  token TOP { <alpha> } # calls Grammar.alpha and uses it at that point
}
```

---

If you noticed I always surrounded the substitution with `[]` as it always acts like an independent sub expression.

Technically none of these are implemented in the way I've shown them, it is just a theoretical model that is easier to explain.

Comment: Thank you very much Brad Gilbert !!! <{}> is really cool !! > say "zzonezz" ~~ m/ <{ say "foo"; "one";}> /
foo
foo
foo
｢one｣

Comment: perl6 just gets better everyday :-)

Comment: `<>` can act like `qw` inside regexes, when you put a space after `<`. Example: `/< a b c>/`

Answer (score 2):

Within regex `<>` are used for what I tend to call "generalized assertions".  Whenever you match something with regex, you're making a series of assertions about what the string should look like.   If all of the assertions are true, the entire regex matches.  For example, `/ foo /` asserts that the string "foo" appears within the string being matched; `/ f o* /` asserts that the string should contain an "f" followed by zero or more "o", etc.

In any case, for generalized assertions, Rakudo Perl 6 uses the character immediately after the `<` to determine what kind of assertion is being made.  If the character after `<` is alphabetic (e.g. `<foo>`) it is taken to mean a named subrule; if the character after `<` is `{`, it's an assertion that contains code that is to be interpolated into the pattern (e.g., `<{ gen_some_regex(); }>`); if the character after `<` is a `[`, it's a character class; if the character after `<` is a `:` then it expects to match an Unicode property (e.g., `<:Letter>`); if the character after `<` is a `?` or `!`, you get positive and negative zero-width assertions respectively;  etc.

And finally, outside of regex, `<>` act as "quote words".  If the character immediately following the `<` is a whitespace character, within regex, it will also act as a kind of "quote words":

```
> "I'm a bartender" ~~ / < foo bar > /
｢bar｣
```

This is matched as if it were an alternation, that is `< foo bar >` will match one of `foo` or `bar` as if you'd written `foo | bar`.